# spark sql - Have disabled Broadcast Hash Join ,but "NOT IN" query still do the mechanism

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, left-join, distributed-computing, anti-join

Here's my spark sql version: 3.1.3

```
SELECT 
 count(
  DISTINCT test_table.name
 ) AS cnt 
FROM 
 test_table 
WHERE 
 test_table.inv_date >= '20230101' 
 AND test_table.inv_date < '20230601' 
 AND (
  test_table.name NOT IN (
   SELECT 
    DISTINCT test_table.name AS name 
   FROM 
    test_table 
   WHERE 
    test_table.inv_date >= '20230101' 
    AND test_table.inv_date < '20230501'
  )
 )
```

[Here's the spark application UI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqtZ1.png)

I would like to ask why the query contains "NOT IN" still do broadcast join even though I have disabled it?

I disabled Broadcast Hash Join (set `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to -1), but the following query still did broadcast.